# Native AAC Streaming in Android

Tags: java, android, stream, aac, icecast

the Android documentation says that certain formats of AAC are supported by the native MediaPlayer however I can't seem to be able to get it to work.

I'm attempting to stream audio via the MediaPlayer, my code works when the stream uses MP3 but not when it uses AAC.

Basically, the code that instantiates and opens the stream is as follows:

```
 Media Player mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
 mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
 mediaPlayer.setDataSource("http://example.com:6000/stream");
 ...
 mediaPlayer.prepare();
 mediaPlayer.start();
```

*The media player is prepared and started asynchronously.

The error message I get is:

```
 Prepare failed.: status=0x1
```

Is there anyway to use the native MediaPlayer to consume an AAC stream?

Or am I forced to use a 3rd party library?

Comment: @ePirat yes, I deleted that question as it was vague and no longer relevant.

Answer (score 0):

It is apparently not possible because implementing a decoder for AAC format requires a license, thus Android framework doesn't have a decoder. From [AAC Licensing page FAQs](http://www.via-corp.com/us/en/licensing/aac/faq.html):

> WHO MUST SIGN A LICENSE?
>        An AAC patent license is needed by manufacturers or developers of end-user encoder and/or decoder products.

However, you can checkout [aacplayer](https://code.google.com/archive/p/aacplayer-android/) and [BASS](http://www.un4seen.com/) for how to implement this for private use.

Also checkout [ExoPlayer](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer).

Comment: Do you mean that the error message `Prepare failed.: status=0x1` is related to the license requirement?

Comment: @EmersonCastaneda Not exactly, it is because of unsupported audio format. From `MediaPlayer` [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html): In general, some playback control operation may fail due to various reasons, such as unsupported audio/video format, poorly interleaved audio/video, resolution too high, streaming timeout, and the like.

Comment: @EmersonCastaneda Clarified the answer about the licensing.